Confusion about spectral sequence of path connected space--Weibel 6.10.10
This is referring to Chapter 6, section 10 on "Covering Space in Topology", in the chapter of group cohomology of Weibel's "Homological Algebra" book.
I'm attaching a picture of the theorem for reference.

My confusion here is: according to proposition 5.7.6 (and it seems to me the proof below) both homology and cohomology case should be referring to the second spectral sequence.
So would the ${}^IE_{pq}^2$ in this case really be ${}^{II}E_{pq}^2$ instead? (since as the proof below also shows, the first spectral sequence would collapse in this case to $H_p(X/G,A)$.)

Yes, in the proof only ${}^{II}E^2$ appears and in the theorem statement it is an honest "typo", if that; I don't think it's very important anyway. As far as I know, you only really care that the spectral sequence exists and vaguely care about how it was constructed; whether it was of type ${}^{II}$ or ${}^I$ is unimportant since you could just transpose the double complex and interchange the two. As the complexes in this case are first quadrant, all finiteness properties are shared by both ${}^I$ and ${}^{II}$; when the complex is unbounded in some directions, then you might begin to worry about this sort of thing apropos convergence.
